# Как изменить False на True с помощью кнопки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет!
Учу React.js. И решил сделать такое приложение.
Хотел бы узнать как изменить False на True с помощью кнопки в Aсtion. Можете объяснить или можно пример. Заранее спасибо!

[image: To Do List]

Comment: он клик по чекбоксу и сетстейт с false на true, если store с redux то создаешь экшен по клику, диспатчишь в редюсер и меняешь в стейте нужное свойство с false на true

Comment: А можно пожалуйста пример чекбокса и сетстейт с false на true.